# Command line MP3 and OGG tagger with picture support (cover fetcher)

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, mp3, tag, ogg-vorbis

I am searching a command-line tagging tool that supports ogg- and mp3-tagging and allows to add a picture to the tags.

Currently I use [lltag](http://home.gna.org/lltag/) but that does not support pictures. [dagger](http://freewarepoint.de/dagger/) is the tool I use before but it is lacking picture support as well.

Answer (score 6):

### [eyed3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/eyed3) ([Install eyed3](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/eyed3))

This works for mp3 files.
Example usage, where `image_name.jpg` is the filename of the image you want for the cover art of the  mp3 file `test.mp3`:

```
eyeD3 --add-image=image_name.jpg:FRONT_COVER test.mp3
```

## [vorbis-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vorbis-tools) ([Install vorbis-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/vorbis-tools))

Vorbis-tools provides the command `vorbiscomment` which can embed images in ogg files if they are encoded correctly. Unfortunately I can't find out exactly how one can encode an image correctly. See [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/169151/embed-album-art-in-ogg-through-command-line-in-linux).

Comment: eyed3 seems only to work for mp3 and not for ogg. So, this one would not help me.

Comment: @ddeimeke I don't think there is any command line tool that supports both, see my updated answer.

Comment: Maybe that there is no tool, but this is what I am searching. The mentioned tools in my questions are doing the tagging for both file types (and even flac). I am search something similar for the pictures. Thanks a lot for your support.